# What type of algorithm does java's indexOf implement

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to figure out what sort of algorithm the `indexOf()` method of `java.lang.String` implements in their source code: http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java/?v=source

```
public int indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex) {
        int max = offset + count;
        char v[] = value;

        if (fromIndex < 0) {
            fromIndex = 0;
        } else if (fromIndex >= count) {
            // Note: fromIndex might be near -1>>>1.
            return -1;
        }

        int i = offset + fromIndex;
        if (ch < Character.MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT) {
            // handle most cases here (ch is a BMP code point or a
            // negative value (invalid code point))
            for (; i < max ; i++) {
                if (v[i] == ch) {
                    return i - offset;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        if (ch <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT) {
            // handle supplementary characters here
            char[] surrogates = Character.toChars(ch);
            for (; i < max; i++) {
                if (v[i] == surrogates[0]) {
                    if (i + 1 == max) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (v[i+1] == surrogates[1]) {
                        return i - offset;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

From what I can tell this should be a bruteforce and no Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm because there is no emphasis on looking for pattern mismatches.

Comment: This function searches for a *single character*. Of course you don't see any KMP code. Why didn't you look into `indexOf(String)`?

Comment: Well, I would have said "searches", but what @MarkoTopolnik said.

Comment: What made you think it might not be brute force?

Comment: It might be more to the point to look at the overloaded method where indeed a String's index is searched for. But, to save you the trouble, it isn't any more sophisticated than the single character search.

Comment: I think the whole substring search of java set me off, considering an array of characters is being searched for and other algorithms search for whole patterns. I think I also confused the BMP commented in the source as KMP

Comment: As @MarkoTopolnik stated, the above algorithm is searching for a *single character*, so no "acceleration" is possible.  The only "odd" thing is the handling of "extended" characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ode uses the **brute force algorithm** to find the `substring` in a given string. That is, the approach runs in **O(mn)**, where `m and n are the length of the source and target strings`.

more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997170/choice-of-algorithm-for-indexof-method-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752274/java-indexofstring-str-method-complexity)